# My table is not hiding when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I want to hide or show my spinner depending on what is selected in the radio button. The spinner is displayed in a table. If the user chose yes (radio button), it will display the table which the spinner is in, if the user chose no (radio button), it will hide the table the spinner is in.

I researched on Google the best way to use style in JavaScript and the one I most commonly found was using `(variable).style.(css property)`.

I have tried this but it hasn't worked. What I want to know is that am I coding this wrong (it is not showing anything in error console and it seems right with the examples I have followed) or do I need to do it another way when it comes to display and hiding tables?

Below is my HTML code:

```html
    <table id="tblWeight">
    <tr>
    <th>6: Provide a Total Weight for your Session</th>
    <td><input type="radio" name="weightChoice" value="yes" onClick="getWeight()"/> Yes</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="weightChoice" value="No" onClick="getWeight()"/> No</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="radioAlert"></div>
        <br/>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Weight (%):</th>
        <td class="spinner"><input type="text" class="spinnerWeight" name="txtWeight" id="txtWeight"></td>
        <td><button class="scrollBtn" id="btnWeightUp" type="button"><img src="Images/black_uppointing_triangle.png" alt="Increase" /></button>
        <button class="scrollBtn" id="btnWeightDown" type="button"><img src="Images/black_downpointing_triangle.png" alt="Decrease" /></button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="weightAlert"></div>
        <br/>
        <table><tr><th>7: Module:</th>
    <td><?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Below is JavaScript code:

```javascript
function getWeight() {
    var weightChoice = document.getElementsByName("weightChoice");               
    var textWeight = document.getElementById("txtWeight");
    var tableWeight = document.getElementById("tblWeight");

    if(weightChoice[0].checked == true){
        tableWeight.style.visibility=="visible";
        textWeight.value == 0;
    } else {
        tableWeight.style.visibility=="hidden";
        textWeight.value == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment statements are written with doubled "=" characters, which makes them not be assignment statements.

```
        if(weightChoice[0].checked == true){
            tableWeight.style.visibility = "visible";
            textWeight.value = 0;
        }else{
            tableWeight.style.visibility = "hidden";
            textWeight.value = 0;
        }
```

The "==" is a comparison operator, so your statements were not *syntactically* erroneous and thus no errors were reported.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `==` to assign, when `==` is an equality comparison operator. It should be `=`:

```javascript
function getWeight() {
    var weightChoice = document.getElementsByName("weightChoice");               
    var textWeight = document.getElementById("txtWeight");
    var tableWeight = document.getElementById("tblWeight");

    if(weightChoice[0].checked) {
        tableWeight.style.visibility = "visible";
        textWeight.value = 0;
    } else {
        tableWeight.style.visibility = "hidden";
        textWeight.value = 0;
    }
}
```

Also, `== true`, which I removed, is *never* necessary. I repeat - *never*. Anywhere you use `== true`, just take it out.

Comment: There are occasions where `if( x == true )` will not provide the same result as `if( x )`, so I wouldn't be quite too quick to recommend taking it out anywhere it is used.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Such as...? I think you're confusing loose equality `==` with identity `===`. (I know, there are some cases in assignment like `someObject.property = a == true;` but that's the same as saying `someObject.property = Boolean(a);` or various other things that are a lot more clear.)

Comment: Because the loose equality performs a `toNumber` conversion, while the `if( x )` will use `toBoolean`, it is possible to get different results. The two examples I can think of are comparing to a String with only whitespace, and comparing to an empty Array. The `toBoolean` will be `true` for those, but the `toNumber` will result in `0`, which is not `== true`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Oh, right! Oops :P I suppose I just never imagined anyone doing `== true` with an empty array.

Comment: Yeah, I'd imagine it would be pretty rare that anyone would actually be using `== true` in either of those cases.